# Remove / Merge / Add vertex where overlapping occurs

Tags: edit-mode, text-object

I'm currently creating text and applying an offset so that the text/font is a bit thicker. This sometimes creates letters that overlap themselves depending on the font used. After converting the text to a curve or mesh I would like to either join these overlapping parts or create a cut where the overlap occurs. I'm curious to know the most efficient way to do this in blender 2.93.

[image: Face]

[image: Curve]

Comment: if you're talking about a mesh, you can use the TinyCAD addon, then select all, right click > TinyCAD > XALL, it will remove the faces, merge by distance, fill the faces

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks! Is there a way to do the same thing or something similar with curves?

Comment: not that I know, but you can convert a mesh to curve

Comment: but keep in mind that you can't create curve vertices that are connected to more than 2 vertices, so your topology must be compatible to this constraint

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the text object in blender?

[image]

You can use the text object like any other text editor (just jump into edit mode with `tab` like normal

[image]

You can add your modifiers as normal (some are not available as with a text object)

[image]

But if you convert your text object to a standard mesh, you can do whatever you want with it

[image]

The geometry is a bit rough, but you can re-topologise it once you're done modifying it if you need to

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that's what I'm doing already. I'm just looking for an automated way to intersect the overlapping parts of a single mesh so that I can dissolve the vertices/edges/faces that do so